# Using UTF-16 syntax to include Unicode characters in Bash prompt (PS1)?

Tags: bash, unicode, ps1

There is an existing post on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/awesome-symbols-and-characters-in-a-bash-prompt) about including Unicode characters in the Bash prompt, but the method it gives for using the UTF-16 code (syntax `\uXXXX`) doesn't work for me.

Let's take this arrow as an example:

> [Unicode Character 'BLACK RIGHTWARDS ARROWHEAD' (U+27A4)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27a4/index.htm)
>
> [image]

As I can see, there should be 3 ways to do Unicode characters in the Bash PS1 prompt:

- UTF-8 Octal value - in this case: `\342\236\244`
- UTF-8 HEX value - in this case: `\xe2\x9e\xa4`
- UTF-16 HEX value (combined) - in this case: `\u27A4`

However, only the first option works in my Ubuntu prompt, as indicated in the image below:

[image]

Explanation:

- With `PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ \342\236\244 '`, the Unicode character is applied correctly.
- With `PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ \xe2\x9e\xa4 '`, the exact string is applied instead.
- With `PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ \u27A4 '`, it applies my username (`am`) and then the exact value `27A4`.

I understand that `\u` is a Bash shortcut for username, which is why I'm confused [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25903/awesome-symbols-and-characters-in-a-bash-prompt) states that this works - for me it doesn't.

Is there a way to make the UTF-16 syntax work for PS1 on Ubuntu (since this is both shorter and easier to read)? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 Server.

Comment: Did you notice the `$'...'` in the other answer, e.g. `PS1=$'\u2234\u2192\u263f\u2605'`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I think I'm working it out. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `\xHH` or `\uHHHH` bash sequences in your pretty prompt, use a `$` before first simple quote like this:

```bash
PS1=$'[\\u@\\h \\W]$ \xe2\x9e\xa4 '
```

or

```bash
PS1=$'[\\u@\\h \\W]$ \u27A4 '
```

Of course, with simple quote, you don't need `\` in before `$`, but with `$'...'` definition, it's better to put two `\\` before each `PS1` special fields (`u`, `h`, `W` in your case)

Comment: Thanks - I missed this detail, because the default Ubuntu prompt starts with: `PS1='${debian_chroot: ...` And I used a simplified example in my question - but it works now! 